# Get epistemic uncertainty of Gaussian process binary classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, gaussian-process

Suppose $f \colon \mathbb R \to \{0, 1\}$ is a random function defined by $P(f(x) = 1)=p(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$, where $p(x)$ is a sigmoid function (goes to zero for $x \to -\infty$, to one for $x \to \infty$, it is continuous and non-decreasing).

I have samples $(x_i, f(x_i))$ for $i = 1, \ldots, N$. I'd like to get an estimate of the function $p$ together with an estimate of its epistemic uncertainty. My goal is having an uncertainty bound, like $p(x) \in [\langle p \rangle(x) - C_\alpha(x), \langle p \rangle(x) + C_\alpha(x)]$, where $\langle p\rangle$ is the mean of $p$ and $C_\alpha$ is an $x$-dependent confidence interval width depending on the confidence level $\alpha$.

Since I don't know a priori the appropriate functional shape of $p(x)$, I thought of Gaussian process classification. With `sklearn`, I can use a `GaussianProcessClassifier` and obtain an estimate of $p(x)$ with the function `predict_proba`. This function does not allow for the keyword `return_std`. Is there a mathematical reason for it?

Here is a code snippet where data is generated with $p$ being a rescaled arctan:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessClassifier
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF, ConstantKernel

# %% 
# Generate synthetic data

beta = 10
prob_func = lambda x: 1 / np.pi * (np.pi / 2 + np.arctan(beta * x))
rng = np.random.default_rng(2024)
N = 100

X = rng.normal(size=N, scale=1/np.sqrt(beta))
Y = rng.binomial(1, prob_func(X), size=N)

plt.plot(X, Y, 'o')
plt.plot(np.sort(X), prob_func(np.sort(X)))

# %%
# Gaussian Process classification

rbf = ConstantKernel(1.0) * RBF(length_scale=1.0)

gpc = GaussianProcessClassifier(kernel=rbf)

gpc.fit(np.reshape(X, (N, 1)), Y)

# %%
# Predict probability

x_test = np.reshape(np.linspace(-3, 3, 1000), (1000, 1))
prob_estimate = gpc.predict_proba(x_test)
estimate = gpc.predict(x_test)

plt.plot(x_test, prob_estimate[:, 1])
plt.plot(x_test, prob_func(x_test))
plt.plot(x_test, estimate)
plt.legend(['GP Estimate', 'Truth'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a flexible enough kernel that will be guaranteed to give a sigmoidal p(x) (i.e. non-decreasing).  I suspect there are some methods for this kind of problem, but they may be too niche for sklearn to support them.